# Base64EncodedString does not include NewLines

Tags: c#, encoding, .net-core, base64

I´m using a .NET core 3.0 project on Windows 10. I´m trying to encode a string to base64 with below code:

```
var stringvalue = "Row1" + Environment.NewLine + "\n\n" + "Row2";
var encodedString = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringvalue));
```

encodedString has then below result:

```
Um93MQ0KCgpSb3cy
```

stringvalue is:

```
Row1\r\n\n\nRow2
```

However, if I´m passing the same value to this site (https://www.base64encode.org/), i´m getting another result:

```
Um93MVxyXG5cblxuUm93Mg==
```

[image]

In visual studio, I tried to resave the file with Unix lineendings, but without any luck:
[image]

I want the string to be encoded as how it´s done in https://www.base64encode.org. Any ideas how to get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the screenshot, I can see that you have entered a different string from the string you used in your C# code. The string you used in https://www.base64encode.org is represented as a C# string literal like this:

```
"Row1\\r\\n\n\\nRow2"
// or
@"Row1\r\n\n\nRow2"
```

So to answer your question:

> I want the string to be encoded as how it´s done in https://www.base64encode.org. Any ideas how to get this done?

You should do:

```
var encodedString = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Row1\\r\\n\n\\nRow2"));
```

But that's probably not what you actually want. Your first attempt at the C# code is more likely to be desired, because *that* is actually a carriage return character, followed by 3 new line characters. The string you entered in https://www.base64encode.org is simply the backslash character followed by the letter r (or n).

You can't really make the output on https://www.base64encode.org match the C# output, because you can only choose one kind of line separator on there. You can only either encode `Row1\r\n\r\n\r\nRow2` or `Row\n\n\nRow2`. Nevertheless, you can check that the C# result is correct by decoding the output using https://www.base64decode.org.

Answer (score 0):

The `\r\n` will be encoded on the website, this is not a newline, these are 4 characters. There is this newline-separator-checkbox, to say you want the windows style, to convert your real world input value:

```
Row1

Row2.
```

I guess your \r\n\n\n is just a mistake,  the website is prepared to convert it to \r\n\r\n only.